# How to sum up values at odd indices in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua

I want to sum up the values at odd string indices as in the following Java example:

```java
String id = "9506265088085";
int[] intArray = new int[id.length()];
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    if (i%2!=0) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id.charAt(i));
    }
} 
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```lua
local id = "9506265088085"
local sum = 0
for i = 2, #id, 2 do
    sum = sum + id:sub(i, i)
end
print(sum)
```

- You need to loop over the even indices in Lua (since it is 1-based). We use a step of `2` and start at the first even index, `2`, for this.
- `id:sub(i, i)` is used to get the i-th character as a substring; due to the `+`, it is coerced to a number - if you wanted this to be more explicit, you could use `tonumber`.